# How to list the files inside ubuntu:16.04 docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

```
I have created docker container for ubuntu:16.04 and spark.
```

my docker image name  `TestDocker`

using spark application I have copied test.txt to container /opt/ml/ location.

when i am executing below command it is showing  like below:

```
docker images


    REPOSITORY                     TAG                   IMAGE ID          CREATED              SIZE
    xx.com/decision-trees-sample   latest              af30271f1528        19 minutes ago      959MB
```

then i try to execute below command

```
docker exec -it decision-trees-sample ls /opt/ml
```

it is showing error.

now I want to check file is copied or not using docker command,is it  possible to check?

how can I list(LS) files contain in /opt/ml/ ?

Answer (score 2):

you can launch a shell inside the container with the

`docker exec`
command, see the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

For example, if the id of your container is 123abcdef, you may do either

`docker exec -it 123abcdef ls /opt/ml`

or open a shell inside your container

`docker exec -it 123abcdef bash`

and then launch `ls` or `find` or any other command

Comment: hi thanks for quick reply,i have tried your suggestion,  still i am getting error I have updated my question can you please help me on this .

Comment: Launch your image so that it becomes a running container `docker run -it myimage bash `  and now you can access this container

Comment: post `docker ps`

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps

> docker exec -it decision-trees-sample

then set the environmental variable as

> export TERM=xterm

then try with

```
docker exec -it 123abcdef ls /opt/ml
```

basically it tell your which kind of terminal you are trying to open.It mainly due to some package not installed regarding terminals, you can also add it to ~/.bashrc file and commit the image.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above answers and `docker exec` is only for running containers but If you really want to explore container image content I would recommend using [container-diff](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-diff)

```
container-diff analyze --type=file <IMG> | grep /opt/ml
```

Comment: thanks for reply i am getting error like  "container-diff: command not found "

Comment: That is expected It isn't there by default, a utility by google. You can follow the installation instructions here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-diff#installation